# How to test workflow errors - sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

My work flow is showing error while run, I dont know how to see the error description

somebody please tell me how to see the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look your logs with [ULS Viewer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/opal/archive/2009/12/22/uls-viewer-for-sharepoint-2010-troubleshooting.aspx). You can filter message level by click the icons in the middle. This can tell you what is going on inside SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Look into SharePoint's ULS logs. You can change the granularity of information being logged from the Central Administration. However, errors such as unhandled exceptions are usually logged by default anyway.